# Ace Editor How To Get Selected Lines

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to get the selected information from Ace Editor. I found the below function that allows you to get the selected text. However, I would like to get the lines of that selection.

```
editor.getSelectedText()
```

In the below image I would expect to get back (rowStart: 5, rowEnd: 12) or something such as this.

[Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto)

[image]

### **Update:**

Wanted to post the exact code that ended up getting used for getting the first and last line in the selection.

```
var editorLines = editor.selection.getAllRanges();
var start = editorLines[0].start.row + 1;
var end = editorLines[0].end.row + 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `editor.selection.getRange()` or `editor.selection.getAllRanges()` for multiselect

Answer (score 0):

you could perhaps use a combination of getCursor() and getSelectedText().

```
editor.getSelectedText().split("\n").length
```

This will give you the number of selected lines, then you can count the starting position by substracting it to your current position.

Hope this helps.